# Admin views page as user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, admin

Hello i need following function. Admin needs to be able "logged" as user. View all pages as user, but still have an admin features. I more than sure that there is exist ready-made solutions for this. If not, please give me advice how to build this and avoid issue when user logged in and admin logged in as this user.

Comment: If you just need an admin + user, with separate controllers, then add boolean admin to User model, else use Devise + CanCan gems. Used them in practice and I like them, easy to install, easy to use and maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about authentication and authorization. For authentication the most popular option right now is [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). For authorization a popular option is [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) (by Ryan Bates of railscasts fame). These two gems work well together and there's a lot of information out there on how to use them. (see below)

As for your question about an admin logging in as a user, here's a [wiki for Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Sign-in-as-another-user-if-you-are-an-admin) on how to do that.

[Screencast on using Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)

[Screencast on using CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)